# Pytorch: RuntimeError: reduce failed to synchronize: cudaErrorAssert: device-side assert triggered

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am running into the following error when trying to train [this](https://github.com/natanielruiz/deep-head-pose/blob/master/code/test_hopenet.py) on [this dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7OEHD3T4eCkVGs0TkhUWFN6N1k/view).

Since this is the configuration published in the paper, I am assuming I am doing something incredibly wrong.

This error arrives on a different image every time I try to run training.

```
C:/w/1/s/windows/pytorch/aten/src/THCUNN/ClassNLLCriterion.cu:106: block: [0,0,0], thread: [6,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1741, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1735, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1135, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.1.1\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Noam/Code/vision_course/hopenet/deep-head-pose/code/original_code_augmented/train_hopenet_with_validation_holdout.py", line 187, in <module>
    loss_reg_yaw = reg_criterion(yaw_predicted, label_yaw_cont)
  File "C:\Noam\Code\vision_course\hopenet\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 541, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Noam\Code\vision_course\hopenet\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 431, in forward
    return F.mse_loss(input, target, reduction=self.reduction)
  File "C:\Noam\Code\vision_course\hopenet\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2204, in mse_loss
    ret = torch._C._nn.mse_loss(expanded_input, expanded_target, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction))
RuntimeError: reduce failed to synchronize: cudaErrorAssert: device-side assert triggered
```

---

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please run it again on CPU. Often the error message is much clearer without a GPU.

Comment: This kind of error generally occurs when using NLL loss or Cross Entropy loss, and when your dataset has negative labels (or labels greater than number of classes). That is also the exact error you are getting ```Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed```

Comment: @akshayk07 This happens on `loss_reg_yaw = reg_criterion(yaw_predicted, label_yaw_cont)` where `reg_criterion = nn.MSELoss().cuda(gpu)`, so I really don't understand what can cause this

Comment: @akshayk07 You were  correct. It appears I missed a paragraph in the paper that wanted me to clean some of the dataset i was using which actually had tags outside of the allowed bins. The error came in a wrong line, which is anoying. If you write an answer that explains that, I will accept.

Comment: @Gulzar But, this kind of error shouldn't occur for MSELoss. Is there any other loss function involved?

Comment: @akshayk07 Yes, there is a Cross Entropy loss, but somehow the error only appears on other lines. I guess some asynchronous code causes this to die on unrelated lines. You can see the code in the link in the question, it is quite short.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I've been trying to run the VaDE model and keep running into this error. It's clearly connected to the binary_cross_entropy() function.

Comment: @mrwheet I did solve it. Carefully reading the paper implies the data was cleaned. Images with tags greater then 99 degrees must be dropped, and the error disappears.

Comment: @mrwheet https://github.com/noamzilo/deep-head-pose if you want to see exactly my code (which is completely unorganized)

Comment: For anyone else reading this, not for this particular paper, this actually happened because the train data had tags outside of the bounds of the cross entropy `n_classes`, as @akshayk07 states correctly in his answer

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This kind of error generally occurs when using `NLLLoss` or `CrossEntropyLoss`, and when your dataset has negative labels (or labels greater than the number of classes). That is also the exact error you are getting Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.

This won't occur for `MSELoss`, but OP mentions that there is a `CrossEntropyLoss` somewhere and thus the error occurs (the program crashes asynchronously on some other line). The solution is to clean the dataset and ensure that `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` is satisfied (where `t` represents the label).

Also, ensure that your network output is in the range 0 to 1 in case you use `NLLLoss` or `BCELoss` (then you require `softmax` or `sigmoid` activation respectively). Note that this is not required for `CrossEntropyLoss` or `BCEWithLogitsLoss` because they implement the activation function inside the loss function. (Thanks to @PouyaB for pointing out).

Comment: Can you explain how come it crashes on other lines?

Comment: It's difficult to say. All of the other issues/questions I have seen get the error on the NLL/cross entropy line. Maybe you could open an issue on the PyTorch GitHub and the devs can help you find some explanation.

Comment: It is possible that your code crashes on other lines because the cuda kernels are not synchronized. Thus, the main kernel may think it is evaluating another line of code whereas it is really waiting for cuda kernels to finish their tasks and synchronize, so when these cuda kernels fail, the debugger indicates that the error occurred at a line different from the actual error source. Again, this is just a theory

Comment: The same error is raised also when using BCELoss and the input is not in the expected range (0-1). In my case I had a missing nn.Sigmoid() on the output of the network. Adding the nonlinearity fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks so much. I've been struggling with this error for hours; been doing instance segmentation and did not count the background in the number of classes; hence, the labels max value did not match.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar error. I was classifying two classes with labels 1 and 2. Changing the labels to 0 and 1 solved the issue.