# Got 512 channels instead of 64 - what should I change in my Autoencoder?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, autoencoder

```
ndf = 128
z_size = 512

# define the model (a simple autoencoder)
class MyNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyNetwork, self).__init__()

        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 6, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(6,16,kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(16,64,kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True))

        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(       
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64,16,kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),        
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(16,6,kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(6,3,kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True))

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(ndf*4*8*16,z_size)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(ndf*4*8*16,z_size)
        self.d1 = nn.Linear(z_size, ndf*4*8*8)
        self.z_size = z_size
        self.d_max = ndf *4

    def encode(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x) 
        x = x.view(x.shape[0], -1)  
        mu = self.fc1(x)
        log_var = self.fc2(x)
        return mu, log_var

    def decode(self,x):
        x = x.view(x.shape[0], self.z_size)
        x = self.d1(x)
        x = x.view(x.shape[0], self.d_max, 8,8)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x

    def reparameterize(self, mu, log_var):
        std = torch.exp(0.5 * log_var)
        eps = torch.randn_like(std)
        return eps.mul(std).add_(mu)

    def forward(self, x):
        mu, log_var = self.encode(x)
        mu = mu.squeeze()
        log_var = log_var.squeeze()
        z = self.reparameterize(mu, log_var)
        return self.decode(z.view(-1, self.z_size, 1, 1)), mu, log_var
```

I have adapted code from a tutorial and I'm currently getting the error 'Given transposed=1, weight of size 64 16 3 3, expected input[16, 512, 8, 8] to have 64 channels, but got 512 channels instead' when attempting to run my auto-encoder.

Could someone please explain how I should further adapt this code, using the CIFAR10 dataset, which a batch size of 16.

Comment: What's the shape of your input image? `32 x 32  x 3` ?

Comment: Yes, 32x32x3 exactly

Answer (score 0):

Skimmed through your code and found that input and output dimension was not proper.

Assuming both the input and output array shape as 32x32x3 I formatted this code.

```
ndf = 128
z_size = 512

# define the model (a simple autoencoder)
class MyNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyNetwork, self).__init__()

        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 6, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(6,16,kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(16,64,kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True))

        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(       
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64,16,kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),        
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(16,6,kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(6,3,kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True))

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(ndf*4*8*16,z_size)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(ndf*4*8*16,z_size)
        self.d1 = nn.Linear(z_size, ndf*4*8*16)
        self.z_size = z_size
        self.d_max = ndf *4

    def encode(self, x):
        x = self.encoder(x) 
        x = x.view(x.shape[0], -1)  
        mu = self.fc1(x)
        log_var = self.fc2(x)
        return mu, log_var

    def decode(self,x):
        x = x.view(x.shape[0], self.z_size)
        x = self.d1(x)
        x = x.view(x.shape[0], 64, 32, 32)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        return x

    def reparameterize(self, mu, log_var):
        std = torch.exp(0.5 * log_var)
        eps = torch.randn_like(std)
        return eps.mul(std).add_(mu)

    def forward(self, x):
        mu, log_var = self.encode(x)
        mu = mu.squeeze()
        log_var = log_var.squeeze()
        z = self.reparameterize(mu, log_var)
        return self.decode(z.view(-1, self.z_size, 1, 1)), mu, log_var
```

Hope this code works :)

Comment: I'm getting 'reduce failed to synchronize: cudaErrorAssert: device-side assert triggered' on `BCE = F.binary_cross_entropy(p.view(-1, 32 * 32 * 3), x.view(-1, 32 * 32 * 3))` where `x is next(train_iterator).to(device)`. Any idea why?

Comment: i found this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60022388/pytorch-runtimeerror-reduce-failed-to-synchronize-cudaerrorassert-device-sid

It seems to be the problem with the labels.

Comment: And regarding reducing the model size you can experiment with different types of convolutional operations like depth-wise and for activation function, i would recommend using LeakyRelu. you can refer this : https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-of-using-Leaky-Rectified-Linear-Units-Leaky-ReLU-over-normal-ReLU-in-deep-learning

Answer (score 0):

The input to the `decoder` (`x = self.decoder(x)` in `forward` function) should have 64 channels as defined by `nn.ConvTranspose2d(64,16,kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)`.

In order to do so, you can do the following change:

- Change `self.d1 = nn.Linear(z_size, ndf*4*8*8)` to `self.d1 = nn.Linear(z_size, ndf*4*8*16)`.
- Change from `x = x.view(x.shape[0], self.d_max, 8,8)` in `decoder` method to `x = x.view(x.shape[0], 64, 32, 32)`

Use the print statements to analyze the shape of input tensor at different layers:

```
ndf = 128
z_size = 512

# define the model (a simple autoencoder)
class MyNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyNetwork, self).__init__()

        self.encoder = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 6, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(6,16,kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.Conv2d(16,64,kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True))

        self.decoder = nn.Sequential(       
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(64,16,kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),        
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(16,6,kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(6,3,kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(True))

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(ndf*4*8*16,z_size)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(ndf*4*8*16,z_size)
        self.d1 = nn.Linear(z_size, ndf*4*8*16)
        self.z_size = z_size
        self.d_max = ndf *4

    def encode(self, x):
        print('encoder')
        print(x.shape)
        x = self.encoder(x)
        print(x.shape) 
        x = x.view(x.shape[0], -1)  
        print(x.shape)
        mu = self.fc1(x)
        print(mu.shape)
        log_var = self.fc2(x)
        print(log_var.shape)
        return mu, log_var

    def decode(self,x):
        print('decoder')
        print(x.shape)
        x = x.view(x.shape[0], self.z_size)
        print(x.shape)
        x = self.d1(x)
        print(x.shape)
        x = x.view(x.shape[0], 64, 32, 32)
        print(x.shape)
        x = self.decoder(x)
        print(x.shape)
        return x

    def reparameterize(self, mu, log_var):
        std = torch.exp(0.5 * log_var)
        eps = torch.randn_like(std)
        return eps.mul(std).add_(mu)

    def forward(self, x):
        mu, log_var = self.encode(x)
        mu = mu.squeeze()
        log_var = log_var.squeeze()
        z = self.reparameterize(mu, log_var)
        return self.decode(z.view(-1, self.z_size, 1, 1)), mu, log_var
```

Comment: I'm getting 'reduce failed to synchronize: cudaErrorAssert: device-side assert triggered' on `BCE = F.binary_cross_entropy(p.view(-1, 32 * 32 * 3), x.view(-1, 32 * 32 * 3))` where x is `next(train_iterator).to(device)`. Any idea why?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with class labels (there might be negative labels): check https://stackoverflow.com/q/60022388/6210807 Try running it on CPU to get better info about error.

Comment: So I am now using binary_cross_entropy_with_logits and it works but I think the number of network parameters is too high as it still hasn't finished training. How should I go about reducing the number of parameters? Currently its 100750451

Comment: Maybe try making the network smaller by removing layers and you can also reduce the number of neurons in layers.