# Pytorch crashes cuda on wrong line

Tags: python, asynchronous, deep-learning, cuda, pytorch

How to see which python line causes a cuda crash down the line in Pytorch, which executes asynchronous code outside of the GIL?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60022388/pytorch-runtimeerror-reduce-failed-to-synchronize-cudaerrorassert-device-sid) is a case where I had Pytorch crash cuda, running [this](https://github.com/natanielruiz/deep-head-pose/blob/master/code/test_hopenet.py) code on [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7OEHD3T4eCkVGs0TkhUWFN6N1k/view) dataset and every run would crash with the debugger on a different python line, making it very difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer in a [completely unrelated thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/is-there-anybody-happen-this-error/17416) in the forums. Couldn't find a Googleable answer, so posting here for future users' sake.

> Since CUDA calls are executed asynchronously, you should run your code
> with
>
> ```
> CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1 python script.py
> ```
>
> This makes sure the right line of code will throw the error message.